# sql with subString

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 fields in DB as follows:

```
table: t_doc_met
t_doc   t_num
PI  200923712291920BM
OI  200923712291920BM
OD  200923712301921OP
PD  200923712301921MO
MR  200923712301921F
BR  200923712305622BM
MR  200923712305622F
OB  200923712305622M1
OR  200923712305622D
MR  200923712314324M1
MR  200923712314324MO
BR  200923712314324BM
PI  200923712314325OP
OI  20092371231433MO
```

I want to pick all records in this table whose t_doc is in  ('PD','OB','OD','OR','MR').
Also pick t_doc  IN ('BR','PI','OI') whose t_num ends with 'BM'

```
select * from t_doc_met where 
t_doc IN ('PD','OB','OD','OR','MR') AND 
( t_doc IN ('BR','PI','OI') AND SUBSTR(t_num, LENGTH(t_num) - 1, 2) IN ('BM'))
```

Comment: What problem are you having doing that? Do you just want an `OR` instead of the first `AND`?

Comment: both. Its part of a bigger sql and this is breaking because of this addition. So trying to understand.

Comment: You can't have an AND there, you're trying to make a single value below to both `IN` lists at the same time, which isn't possible...

Comment: The question is not about SQL, or about programming at all. It is logic and nothing else. Please review the meaning of operators `AND` and `OR` - in logic, not in programming. With so little understanding of what each does there is absolutely no hope you will write correct code in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `AND` in place of `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_doc_met
WHERE
    (t_doc IN ('PD','OB','OD','OR','MR'))
    OR 
    (t_doc IN ('BR','PI','OI') AND SUBSTR(t_num, -2) IN ('BM'))
```

Note that Oracle's `SUBSTR` takes negative indexes to mean "start from the back". Hence I rewrote your

```
SUBSTR(t_num, LENGTH(t_num) - 1, 2) IN ('BM')
```

as

```
SUBSTR(t_num, -2) IN ('BM')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to interpret the question as saying:  You want all t_docs

- that do not end in bm
- that have a row with t_doc IN ('PD', 'OB', 'OD', 'OR', 'MR')
- that have a row with t_doc IN ('BR','PI','OI')

If this is correct:

```
select dm.t_num
from t_doc_met dm
where t_num LIKE '%BM'
group by t_num
having sum(case when t_doc IN ('PD', 'OB', 'OD', 'OR', 'MR') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t_doc IN ('BR','PI','OI') then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Alternatively, you might just want `or`:

```
select dm.t_num
from t_doc_met dm
where (t_doc IN ('PD', 'OB', 'OD', 'OR', 'MR')) or
      (t_num LIKE '%BM' and ('BR', 'PI', 'OI'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for rows where `t_doc` is in 'PD','OB','OD','OR','MR'; and *at the same time* is in 'BR','PI','OI'. Those are mutually exclusive.

You appear to just want the first `AND` to be an `OR`:

```
select * from t_doc_met where 
t_doc IN ('PD','OB','OD','OR','MR') OR 
( t_doc IN ('BR','PI','OI') AND SUBSTR(t_num, -2) IN ('BM'));

T_ T_NUM            
-- -----------------
PI 200923712291920BM
OI 200923712291920BM
OD 200923712301921OP
PD 200923712301921MO
MR 200923712301921F 
BR 200923712305622BM
MR 200923712305622F 
OB 200923712305622M1
OR 200923712305622D 
MR 200923712314324M1
MR 200923712314324MO
BR 200923712314324BM

12 rows selected.
```

I've also simplified your substr's second argument, as dasblinkenlight mentioned you could do.

If this is part of a bigger query then you need to make sure that the conditions are enclosed in parentheses appropriately, so the parser can interpret the overall logic you intend:

```
select * from t_doc_met where 
-- some other conditions
AND (t_doc IN ('PD','OB','OD','OR','MR') OR 
  (t_doc IN ('BR','PI','OI') AND SUBSTR(t_num, -2) IN ('BM')));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created the sample database for you with same data records that you have provided.

Table:
[image]

Hope this query helps you, modify the "AND/OR" based on your requirements.

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categoryName in  ('PD','OB','OD','OR','MR')  OR (categoryName in ('BR','PI','OI') and description like '%BM' )
```

I have used OR condition to get both the record set of t_doc is in ('PD','OB','OD','OR','MR'). Also pick t_doc IN ('BR','PI','OI') whose t_num ends with 'BM'

Note: I have modified the Table Name and column names

[image]